# Xcode builds on Debug but not on Release

Tags: objective-c, ios, debugging, release, build-settings

So, I have this problem when trying to build my project.

Currently If I run the project in Debug mode, it runs fine, the app starts up on the device and I can test stuff.

However the weird part is when i switch over to the Release build and try to build on the device. When I press the Run button  Xcode builds as normal and the build succeeded notification even pops up, but then I get this error code.

Lets call my app xxx

#### Could not launch "xxx.app"

No such file or directory:

```
/Users/*my Name*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*Bunch of xcode folders*/Products/Release-iphoneos/xxx.app/xxx
```

I went into finder and searched up xxx.app and couldn't find it. Furthermore there doesn't even exist a Library folder under /Users/*my Name*/.

So what is xcode trying to do here, and what should I do to fix this?

**Edit:** I have also tried Cleaning the project and building again, the error code still comes up.

Comment: The Library folder is hidden by default. Use `chflags nohidden ~/Library` to unhide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I get this crap all the time.

What I do is `clean the project`, `close it`, `shut down Xcode`, `start up Xcode`, `open project`, then `build and run`.

If that still does not work then find the "DerivedData' folder `Organizer->Projects` and delete it, then do the above again and try again.

Comment: I did what you said, I command+Q xcode, moved DerivedData to the trash and emptied trash, restarted Xcode and rebuilt the project and the error code still came up. I'm on xcode 4.4.1 if thats any help and also I went into the Release-iphoneos folder only 3 files are in there a libvorbis.a xxx and xxx.app.dSYM

Edit: I did it again, and it worked!! Thank you so much

Comment: What a crock that we all have to experience this from time to time - always trying to figure out what we did wrong :-(

Comment: I should add that as of Xcode 5, I don't recall ever having to do this.

Comment: Someone just upvoted this, so I took a look at my answer. 9 years ago I mentioned I didn't have to do it anymore. Xcode 5 must have been great, as I still have to do the above from time every year!

Answer (score 1):

I tried creating a new scheme and setting it to Release mode. That worked for me. However, a reboot after closing xCode seems to work, too.

Answer (score 0):

> I went into finder and searched up xxx.app and couldn't find it. Furthermore there doesn't even exist a Library folder under /Users/my Name/.

It does exist, but it's hidden (since OSX Lion) in the Finder (because standard users -- as opposed to developers -- should not mess with it).

Some utilities (on a simple command line) can make it visible again but the simplest thing to do is to use "Go" menu of the Finder and select "Go to folder…" (Command-Shift-G). Then copy/paste the path you want to go to and validate.