# Xcode C++ : Build in Debug but not Release

Tags: c++, xcode, release

I am coding in Xcode 6, c++.
I can build and run fine my program in debug, but I somehow can't compile in Release mode.
The error I see is :
Apple LLVM 6.0 Error Could not read profile: No such file or directory

I don't really know what this means... ( I still get this after reducing the main.cpp file to a usual "Hello World" program)

I have tried, as suggested in 
[Xcode builds on Debug but not on Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409510/xcode-builds-on-debug-but-not-on-release)
to clean my project, close it, close Xcode restart and rebuild, or even deleting Derived Data but I still have the same problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Many thx

T

Comment: I'm having the same problem under Xcode 6.1. Btw. giving down votes without explanation is quite meaningless...

Answer (score 6):

I found out the answer to my question.
You have to specify : "Use Optimisation Profile" to false

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I mistakenly changed flag once to true.